# java updating text area

Tags: java, textarea

for my application I have to build a little customized time ticker which ticks over after whatever delay I tell it to and writes the new value in my textArea. The problem is that the ticker is running fully until the termination time and then printing all the values. How can I make the text area change while the code is running.

```
while(tick<terminationTime){
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis()) > (msNow + delay)){
        msNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        tick = tick + 1;
        currentTime.setText(""+tick);
        sourceTextArea.append(""+tick+"  " +  System.currentTimeMillis() +" \n");
    }
}
```

currentTime and sourceTextArea are both text areas and both are getting updated after the while loop ends.

Comment: Are you running this code on the event dispatch thread? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: have you tried calling repaint() on the object you're updating?

Comment: Is this within an action listener?

Comment: this is within the action listener..is that the problem? how do I fix it? 
I did try calling the repaint method, it does not work.
I tried running it in a different thread but that does not fix it as well.

Comment: looks like the listener is the problem.  look at my examlpe for doing the update in another thread, so the listener can finish.

Comment: don't spin a while loop like that w/o a blocking call to sleep() or some other function that yields thread control for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using the `SwingWorker` class (check it out in the javadocs) and the `get()` method that comes along with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that works with 2 threads.

Here is the update thread.

```
public class updateThread extends Thread
{
textAreaTest aa;
Integer i;
public updateThread(textAreaTest abc)
   {
            aa = abc;
            i = 0;
   }

@Override
   public void run()
   {
        while(true)
            {
                try
                  {
                      sleep(1000);
                  }
              catch (InterruptedException e)
                  {
                      //e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              aa.setText(i.toString());
              i++;
            }
   }

}
```

And here is the Jpanel

```
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class textAreaTest extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new textAreaTest();
    }

public textAreaTest()
    {
        updateThread thread = new updateThread(this);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(area);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        Container c = this.getContentPane();
        c.add(area);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        thread.start();
    }

public void setText(String text)
    {
        area.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: good ideas here, but don't use e.printStackTrace() on an InterruptedException which can happen under reasonable circumstances.